# Passing a List of strings from .java to .jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a `List<String>`  in my .java file and I want to get an array of strings in my jsp file. Can this be done using `model.addAttribute`? I dont want to use scriptlets.

Comment: You can use JSTL tags in the JSP

Comment: This can be done and there is tutorial showing how to use JSTL that will show you how to pass your list from the Servlet to the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring, you can pass List with modelAttribute.
In Controller you put:

```
List<String> yourList = ...
model.addAttribute("yourList", yourList);
```

The first attribute is the name of variable in jsp and second is the controller variable.

In jsp you can get yourlist:

```
<c:set var="jspList" value="${yourList}" />
```

Then, you can use list in jsp with `${jspList}`

I hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose that your java class is actually a @Controller (you tagged your question with Spring) and your JSP is the view. Indeed you can use model attributes to pass objects between a Spring controller and view.

Avoiding scriptlets depends on What you want to do with that list in JSP, but JSTL would be your best bet.